# Как сделать, чтобы столбец мог принимать только уникальные значения, кроме пустых

Tags: mysql, sql, double

Пытаюсь добавить к полю ключ UNIQUE
Естественно, выходит ошибка о повторных записях
Пустых.
Как сделать, чтоб не было повторов, но разрешить пустые значения в нём?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: какая база данных?

Comment: База данных MySQL, таблица InnoDB, если это важно, я не знаю

Comment: MySQL должен игнорировать пустые значения https://stackoverflow.com/a/3712251/11619532. У вас колонка в ключе одна? Дополните вопрос подробностями, пожалуйста.

Comment: добавил скрин в вопрос

Comment: А 'Пустая колонка', на сколько она пуста, она имеет значение NULL или пустую строку ? В первом случае она должна позволять дубли, а вот во втором - нет

Comment: @Mike, была пустая строка. Переписал все в NULL, индекс добавился. Спасибо, перенесите коммент в ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В уникальном индексе не учитываются и могут повторяться только NULL значения. Судя по всему у вас в поле пустая строка, такие значения подчиняются общему правилу уникальности и повторяться не могут.